# R Random Forest handling Posixct Values

Tags: r, random-forest, posixct

I am using the randomForest package for a supervised learning. It is running fine, but I have a question regarding POSIXct values. Three of my 45 features are dates or dates with time. They are all considered important features according to the varImPlot. I tried to find out how randomForest uses POSIXct formats to make a prediction, but I couldnt find anything.
Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date-time is usually converted to numeric features (with start date as 1970-01-01). So what you are probably seeing is the effect of time index. A better approach would be to create separate features for day, month, year (in addition to time index) and then check for varImp

```
> as.numeric(as.Date("1970-01-03"))
[1] 2
> as.numeric(as.Date("2010-12-29"))
[1] 14972
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I already have the year, day and month features. I will convert the date to time index.

Comment: I meant it is internally converting POSIXct column to index